# preg replace to match the closest pattern

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have the following string

```
$message = "[quote=azerty]ce que je comprend pas c'est pourquoi j'ai due m'inscrire sur MQL5 ? [/quote]
C'est valable pour le système de signaux dans son ensemble, donc MT4 et MT5
[quote=azerty]si je mets le signal public ça change quoi ? [/quote]
Tu dois surtout mettre ton signal en gratuit, sinon tu devras payer pour suivre tes trades."
```

I am using the following code to match

```
callback_function($match) {
    return "$match[1] wrote: <blockquote class='uncited'><p>$match[2]</p></blockquote>";
}

 $str = preg_replace_callback("/\[quote=\"([^\"]+)\"\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is", "callback_function", $message);
```

Instead of matching the 1st occurence of quote with 2nd occurence, it is matching with 4th occurence.
Any way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that may be corrected in your code:

1. You're trying to match quoted text in the `[quote]` tags, but there are no double quotes in `[quote=azerty]`. Hence this part of your pattern will never match: `\"([^\"]+)\"`.
   We can change it to `([^\]]+)`, to match any characters except `]`.
2. There's no need to use a callback here, because you're not evaluating the match before the replacement. Simply use `preg_replace()`.

**Code:**

```
$pattern = '/\[quote=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is';
$replacement = "$1 wrote: <blockquote class='uncited'><p>$2</p></blockquote>";
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message);
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/SZaLDz)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I had put the " by mistake in the question. but preg_replace works better than preg_replace_callback. Also it replaces all the occurences. Thank you so much.